# Changing the x & y cords of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to change the X and Y coordinates of where the image is. So if someone presses any of the arrow keys, the image will move accordingly. (As well as the image rotating according to the mouse position)

```
$(function () {
var img = $('.image');
var offset = img.offset();
var value = 200;
function mouse(e) {
var centerX = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
var centerY = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
var mouse_x = e.pageX; var mouse_y = e.pageY;
var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - centerX, mouse_y - centerY);
var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}
$(document).mousemove(mouse);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a keydown event. You'll need to find which key has been pressed (i.e. up/left/right/down), and absolutely position the image accordingly, like so:

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
  var img = $('#img');

  function moveLeft(value) {
    img.css('left', function() {
        return parseInt(img.css('left'), 10) + value + 'px';
    });
  }

  function moveTop(value) {
    img.css('top', function() {
        return parseInt(img.css('top'), 10) + value + 'px';
      });
  }

  switch(event.keyCode) {
    // Left arrow
    case 37:
      moveLeft(-100);
      break;

    // Up arrow
    case 38:
      moveTop(-100);
      break;

    // Right arrow
    case 39:
      moveLeft(100);
      break;

    // Down arrow
    case 40:
      moveTop(100);
      break;
  }
});
```

Of course, there's a *lot* of optimising that could be done here, but it works.

CodePen Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEbbMm